# Provide audio data as buffer to ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to provide audio data stored in buffer instead of file to ffmpeg. I don't want to provide file path for audio file.
Is it possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes.  Just execute FFmpeg as a child process, and pipe data to it via STDIO.  Use `-` as the input file, and be sure to set the correct format for your audio data.  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/audio%20types